# Add new data to existing SharePoint xlsx files

Tags: python, sharepoint, xlsx

I would like to write into an existing xlsx file in SharePoint. Is that even possible? Mydata is in the form of a dataframe and if possible, just append the dataframe instead of overwriting the whole xlsx file. I tried to use xlsxwriter library but did not get anywhere. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: SharePoint is onpremises or online?

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo online

Answer (score 0):

@Coder123,

As you're using SP Online, you could update the content of xlsx file stored in SPO via MS Graph API:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

through this API, you can update the table/worksheet of an xlsx file. And it has offered a python library:

- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core

Comment: could you give me a sample code on how to update a xlsx sharepoint table using this library? Thanks!